# Meaning of "premise of something?"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, logic

In the following question:

- What's the premise of money?
- What's the premise of email?
- What's the premise of the book / movie?

Does the word 'premise' refer to the reason behind the existence of money, email, the book?

What I know is that premise refers to a part of an argument that leads to a conclusion:

- Premise #1: All swans are white
- Premise #2: Jill is a swan.
- Conclusion: Jill is white.

When I am asking the 'premise of something', does it have the same meaning? What's the conclusion in case of money, email or book?

Answer (score 2):

***Premise*** has subtly different meanings in philosophy (where you have a list of premises and a conclusion, for instance), and in everyday use, where you talk about the premise of a film or book. Actually one academic I know pronounces them differently - PREM-iss for the everyday use, and prem-IZE for the philosophy use.

The premise of a work is the underlying principle of it, the starting point, the thing that makes that book, film, play, or argument *go*.

The premise of a concept, like money, is a similar idea - what is the fundamental point and underlying assumption of the idea of money?

Comment: Can I think of it as the 'core idea' behind the existence of money, theory or a concept? Or, what makes a concept work?

Comment: @user92131: Yes, it's kind of both of those. And some things can arguably have more than one premise (especially art - books, film etc), though I understand some critics say that makes for a bad creation.

Answer (score 0):

Premise [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/premise):

> an idea or theory on which a statement or action is based.

Exemples:

> The conclusions you have drawn are based on a false **premise**.
>
> We should work on the **premise** that this plan will be successful.
>
> Could you explain the basic **premise** of your argument?
>
> The research project is based on the **premise** stated earlier.

About your question:

- *What's the **premise** of money?*

The meaning is close to the following:

- *What is the **principle** of money ?*